# How do I disable the "fn + F8" shortcut?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, keyboard

As I need to use the <kbd>*fn*</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> shortcut within my virtual machine, I'd like to disable it in my host.

How do I go about disabling this particular shortcut, so that it can be used within my VM?

Comment: Does fn-F8 mean the normal F8 key or a symbolic hotkey or media key under F8? In the latter case, see [Documenting com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist - The macosxhints Forums](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=114785).

Answer (score 1):

Try installing **[KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/document.html)**. It's a free and powerfull utility for keyboard customization for MacOS X.

Comment: that doesn't allow you to get completely away from binding your F8 key to the media controls.  The options in KeyRemap, all of them use F8 for something for media, there is no option that excludes F8

Answer (score 0):

you can edit all your keyboard shortcuts. in system preferences->keyboard ->keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Special keys (like brightnes, volume and playing controls) are not configurable via the Keyboard prefpane

Comment: fn f8 is available there on my laptop (spaces). I unchecked the use all f1,f2,f3 keys as standard functions under keyboard in system preferences, maybe that's the cause.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/document.html), there is also [DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/) (free and open source).